# ¿Cómo se puede contar desde el fin de una serie?

Tags: números

Entiendo que se puede decir último, penúltimo y antepenúltimo para describir las últimas tres posiciones. Pero más alla de penúltimo no sé como describir las posiciones que siguen.

En inglés hay una forma general de usar el ordinal con la frase "from/to last," pero buscando en Google por lo visto, hay muy pocos resultados por frases como "sexto desde el último."

Comment: Cuarto, quinto, sexto ... **por la cola** o **desde el final**

Comment: preantepenúltimo, protopreantepenúltimo, alborprotopreantepenúltimo…

Comment: Acabo de encontrar esta información:  https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/penúltimo-antepenúltimo-¿y-después.2961425/

Comment: Bien, @aris, ahora, ¡a redactar una respuesta, por favor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongamos que tienes 20 personas en una clasificación. Efectivamente, si contamos desde el final los tres primeros términos serían:

- último
- penúltimo
- antepenúltimo

En mi experiencia, es muy común usar ***por la cola*** para continuar:

- cuarto por la cola
- quinto por la cola
- ...

Donde el enésimo por la cola se entiende como que está en la posición *n* empezando por detrás. Así, el último sería el primero por la cola.